# How to set a static IP using netplan? (running Ubuntu Bionic server)

Tags: networking, netplan

**My problem is that no static IP is getting assigned to the built-in ethernet port**. I have run `netplan apply` several times. I've also rebooted the PC and still no luck.

I am sure the ethernet port works as I was previously using it on Ubuntu 16.04 just before I decided to fresh install 18.04.2.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I am going to use the ethernet port to connect my main PC to the Ubuntu server via a crossover cable.

If I set the ethernet port to use `dchp4:true` and connect an ethernet cable from it to my modem/router and disable my WiFi card (by removing the netplan config), the PC can connect to the net without any issues.

Thanks

---

This is the output of `netplan --debug apply` which also shows the contents of my YAML files. I have tried with and without dhcp4/dchp6/gateway4/renderer.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had sucess with interfaces file, like previous version. With following static ip config like eth0 in the  following example.

> root@redbird:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

`auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
        address 192.168.0.130
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1`

** Broadcast and Network lines are optional **
and simply an ifup.

> "ifup enp3s0" .

Is network-manager defined as renderer ?..

> Disable networkd and run netplan to see if it is applying the config.

Comment: I first tried that but when I viewed /var/log/syslog, I got messages there that goes like "you're doing it the wrong way". This then prompted me to search the net on the way of doing network stuff on Ubuntu Bionic.